# File format for Enrichment Map

Tags: cytoscape

I have a list of genes that I would like to analyze using Enrichment Map App on Cytoscape to see possible enrichments. I don't know what is the file format I should use. Looks like .txt or .xls files won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the Enrichment Map doc pages: https://enrichmentmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats.html

-- scooter